# How to set name for a laravel fortify route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I'm a little curious, sorry for the silly question.

I wanted to get the route for login in the Laravel 8 + Fortify stack, it seems I cannot use "/login" directly because it will append on URL. so I wanted to use

```
{{ route('login') }}
```

But the problem is, it gives me an error 'route not defined'. When I'm running the command `route:list` it shows a blank name for login and register but has a name for 'logout'

I wonder how I can give a name for the fortify route, as it is not declared in the `routes.web`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

This will clear all the route cache in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You should Try :

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

It help you clear your application cache route and config as well.